# Which is a better method for me to make my web app usable on a mobile

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I have a web app which uses html and javascript to display (graphs, reports, tables) and sometimes update data which is queried and controlled using a tomcat java controller and stored in a mySQL database. There is a lot of data in this db and it gets more data on a daily basis.

I now want to make this usable on both android and iOS.
The easiest way to do this, in my opinion, would be to just make a web app for a mobile device.

But people I've talked to say that it's always better to develop it as a native app for both platforms.

I've also come across a third option by using a framework to develop an app for both at the same time. Such as...
•   C# - http://xamarin.com/

•   Java - http://www.codenameone.com

•   Web APIs (HTML, Javascript) - http://phonegap.com/

•   Titanium (html, Javascrip) - http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/

I have now so many options and I really don't know how to choose. I mean why wouldn't I just choose the easiest way?

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

There can be a lot of bias in answering this question. However, there are some non-bias considerations that would help you to proceed appropriately.

1. If you are uncertain of the mobile experience, user traction, etc. and you have no other constraints or requirements (i.e. you don't have a boss or board of directors telling you to build an enterprise level solution) then go with the easiest route.
2. If you're confident of user adoption of your site/app but you're not skilled or don't have a budget for native apps, go with the cross-platform tool. It will expose your app to the most markets with the least effort.
3. If you have design constraints for native platform development (i.e. need to access native features) or business requirements (i.e. your boss says you have to), then go with native development.

While many may argue the pros/cons of any approach, fundamentally if you are going into an unproven market, it's best to start cheap, fast and easy. Developing for mobile is completely different from developing for desktops / web access. You will probably learn a lot and have to make many adjustments to expectations and product direction as you gain experience in mobile markets. While I'm a big fan of native development, I probably would not do that in your case, with what you have said so far.